# Import OSM data in postgis with python script

Tags: python, postgis, openstreetmap, osmosis

I want to import OSM data (way and nodes) in postgis database with a script pyhton, I found in the internet that I should create a schema but I don't know how and I really don't know what to put on the script and which library should I use.

Comment: Why python? Did you already look at osm2pgsql, osmosis, imposm or a similar tool that is designed for this task?

Comment: I choose python because all the processing that I made are on it.

Comment: Then take a look at [imposm](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Imposm) which is written in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the question mentions not knowing how to create a schema.  You can create a schema with pgAdmin (GUI) or with this SQL statement:

```
CREATE SCHEMA tiger_data;
```

I recommend you install the PostGIS TIGER Geocoder.  This extention creates scripts (windows and linux) to download and import US Census shapefiles.  You can learn a lot from the process that the scripts follow and incorporate the same methods for your shapefiles.